# Choosing a Sample Size for a SOM Cluster

Tags: sample-size, self-organizing-maps

Is there an accepted formula to determine a good lower bound for the number of samples needed for the initial input on an SOM clustering algorithm?

For example - If I know that there are X number of attributes, and I suspect that there are at least Y distinct groups, and I have an input of 4 million line items - it will take a few days to process, so we'd like to take a simple random sample of those 4 million but we don't know how many we should take.

A related question is, how can we predict how long it would take to process x number of entries with y number of unique attritubes.